# Склонение названий городов

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть такие названия городов, которые в русском языке ассоциируются с множественным числом (хотя, конечно, им не являются). Например, Афины, Канны, Саки или Хельсинки. Но распространяются ли правила склонения существительных множественного числа на эти города и правильно ли распространять на них эти правила?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Краткой русской грамматике (1989) в разделе "Несклоняемые существительные" (§ 184) говорится, что не склоняются иноязычные топонимы, оканчивающиеся на гласные (**кроме -а, -ы**), такие как: Баку, Сухуми, Хельсинки, Чили, Кале и т.п. Иноязычные географические названия на **-ы** (слова pluralia tantum) склоняются: *Татры — из Татр, Канны — в Каннах, Микены — около Микен*. Отвечая на ваш вопрос: слова *Афины, Канны* склоняются, *Хельсинки* — нет. Название *Саки* склоняется, хотя по правилам не должно. Может быть, оно не воспринимается как иностранное?

Answer (score 1):

Саки — точно не иностранное. Происхождение не русское, но обрусевшее. Видимо потому, что находятся в зоне преимущественного употребления русского я зыка. Как Жигули.
Другого критерия я не знаю.